# fiddlercore to mock responses for testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fiddler, fiddlercore

I need to simulate web response for web requests during some tests. I was going to use fiddler core for that. So fiddler just acts like a proxy and Im able to set response for every request I like. But I need to run something like console application or standalone application to make fiddler core able to intercept the requests. And I need it to be somehow initialized inside my asp.net mvc test application, so that tester could access these fake data, by just using the urls, without the need to run fiddler or any other applications.

For now I tried to run my fiddler application in Controller action method, but it doesnt intercept anything.
I also tried to add `URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:"+ myPort, "")`, but it doesnt work either.

Is there any way to self host fiddler core app and make it intercept the requests?

UPDATE:
In the end I managed to host fiddler core inside asp.net mvc app. I made initialization in a static method of a static class and it did the trick. Also, for some reason after calling shutdown and then performing initialization again I cant proxify anything. I even cal GC.Collect, nothing helps, but refreshing the host process, in my case IIS express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, `SetProxyInProcess` affects URLMon clients only, and .NET doesn't use URLMon for networking.

.NET clients typically pick up the current proxy setting automatically, but if you're running FiddlerCore in a different user account, that's not going to work (and you probably don't want your mocker to be messing with any traffic except your test application). So, instead you should configure your application explicitly to proxy its traffic through your FiddlerCore instance; see http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET and  http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-IIS and if your services are local http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: Checking on the links. thanks for a quick reply, looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Eric, is it possible to hook asp.net mvc application from itself? I mean by adding `FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest` handler and `FiddlerApplication.Startup` in controller action method. And then catch request in other action methods of this app?

Comment: It *may* be possible for your ASP.NET application to directly host FiddlerCore, but I'm guessing that it probably won't work due to how the ASP.NET lifecycle works; you'd probably end up tearing down FiddlerCore after each response. But that's really a question for an ASP.NET guru.

Comment: What if I preserve it in session object or elsewhere? the problem is only in that objects cerated in action method are cleaned after every response? Also creating everything as static object should be sufficient as they are not disposed per request.